# selective compilation of template

Tags: c++, templates, compilation

Is there a way to pre-compile some template instantinations (of a class template) but not all, so that the remaining are compiled when instantinated (w/o errors at linking)?

To demonstrate the issue, consider this example:

```
// file.h
template<typename T> class object { /* lots of code */ };

// file.inc
template<typename T>
object::object(const T*data) { /* ... */ }
    // and more: definitions of all non-inline functionality of class object<>

// file.cc to be compiled and linked
#include "file.h"
#include "file.inc" 

template struct<int>;
template struct<double>;

// user.cc
#include "user.h"
#include "file.h"

object<double> x{0.4}                              // okay: uses pre-compiled code
object<user_defined> z(user_defined{"file.dat"});  // error: fails at linking
```

If instead the user `#include`s `"file.inc"`

```
// user.cc
#include "user.h"
#include "file.h"
#include "file.inc"

object<double>  x{0.4}                            // error: duplicate code 
object<user_defined> z(user_defined{"file.dat"}); // okay
```

the compiler will find another compiled version due to the pre-compiled code from `file.cc`.

So how can I avoid both of these problems? I reckon a related question would be "how can I specify that a pre-compiled header fully compiles a template for certain template parameters (only)?"

Comment: You don't use include guards or #pragma once in your header files?

Comment: @ÖöTiib I do, but this example shall remain short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `extern template` to prevent a particular instantiation of a template in a given TU.

```
// src0.cpp

template class foo<int>;
    // Oblige instantiation of `foo<int>` in this TU
```

```
// src1.cpp

extern template class foo<int>;
    // Prevent instantiation of `foo<int>` in this TU
```

As long as `src0` and `src1` are linked together, your program will work.